# How to get Play framework working on CentOS?

Tags: playframework

I have a feeling this is going to be a very stupid question, but I'm tired of reading documentation endlessly without even being sure that I'm on the right path.

I'm trying to get the Play framework working on my server. I have root access to this server, and it uses CentOS as the operating system. I'm able to get the Play framework working perfectly on my local OS X machine using the brew package manager, but I can't seem to find the Play framework using the yum package manager (what CentOS uses), so I have to download and install the framework manually, which is what I'm currently having trouble with.

So far, all I've done is copy the Play framework install file to the CentOS machine using wget and unzip it. I run this:

```
wget http://download.playframework.org/releases/play-2.0.4.zip
unzip play-2.0.4.zip
```

A directory is created called "play-2.0.4" and all of the files associated with the framework are in it. I'm not sure what to do next. If I go into this directory and type `play`, it just says "bash: play: command not found", even though the file "play" is definitely in the current directory and is executable. I issue `chmod +x play` just to be sure and it still will not execute. I think this is the file that I need to execute to get the framework working, but I'm not sure. I am relatively new to Linux and server management, so if you could guide me in the right direction, it would help me out a lot.

Comment: You should try ./play instead since it is probably not on your path

Comment: THANK YOU! It works. I just needed the ./ to indicate current directory. Wow. What a simple answer. I tried adding it to my path but I linked to the actual executable, not the comprising directory. I added it to $PATH and it works now as well without the ./ to indicate current directory. Thanks for taking the time to read my question and answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. Set path to the `play` folder. Open the terminal and type:

   echo "export PATH=$PATH:[path-to-your-play-folder]" >> ~/.bashrc

   source ~/.bashrc
2. Create a soft link to your bin folder

   sudo ln -s /play /usr/bin/